# Trying to access XAMPP database from another domain

Tags: mysql, xampp

I just need some help with accessing my DB. I'm moving my websites from XAMPP to a hosting provider is there any way of allowing XAMPPs MySQL DB to be accessed outside of its IP. When I tried to do this I cant a simple Connection Refused error.

I need to use the XAMPP DB because a python script I have for some reason doesnt work with my hosting provider DB.

'Localhost' XAMPP Server DB ---DATA---> 'www.example.com'

Comment: hosting sites have their own database, much better to migrate or import your xampp database.

Comment: I need to use the XAMPP DB because a python script I have for some reason doesnt work with my hosting provider DB.